# Fetch only those records from table join which has not reached its final state

Tags: mysql

if have two tables A and B:

```
Table A                    
id work_name
1   10001
2   10002
```

and

```
Table B
id work_id final_status
1   1      0
2   2      0
3   1      1
```

i have to fetch only those work_id whose final status is not 1
In Above Table output should 2 as final_status of work_id 1 is reached to 1.
I have tried the Query but it is not giving me desired result

My Query:

```
select B.work_id from A inner join B on A.id = B.work_id where final_status!=1
```

My Result:

```
1 
2
```

I want to exclude 1 as it has reach to its final status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to produce the required output:

- join table B twice on table A
- join table B once, get the `max()` of final_status and filter in `having` clause
- combination of `in()` and `not in()` subqueries
- combination of `exists()` and `not exists()` subqueries

I prefer the last method because `exists()` / `not exists()` do not have to actually fetch the data from table B:

```
select A.*
from A
where exists(select 1 from B where B.work_id=A.id and B.final_status=0)
    and not exists(select 1 from B where B.work_id=A.id and B.final_status=1)
```